# Combining all key value pairs in one using jq filter or jq play

Tags: json, foreach, jq

I want to transform JSON data using jq filter

Json data:

```
{
 "main": [
  {
   "firstKey": "ABCD",
   "id": "12345",
   "data": [
    {
     "name": "first_id",
     "value": "first_id_value"
    },
    {
     "name": "second_id",
     "value": "second_id_value"
    },
    {
     "name": "third_id",
     "value": "third_id_value"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

**Expected OUTPUT**:

```
{
 "firstKey": "ABCD",
 "id": "12345",
 "data.name.first_id": "first_id_value",
 "data.name.second_id": "second_id_value",
 "data.name.third_id": "third_id_value"
}
```

After many trials and errors, I was near to expected output using following filter expression

```
[.main[]|{"firstKey", "id"},foreach .data[] as $item (0; "data.name.\($item.name)" as $a|$item.value as $b| {($a): $b})][]
```

Used foreach as **objects under "data" are dynamic**. the number of objects can differ.
The output for the above expression is:

```
{
  "firstKey": "ABCD",
  "id": "12345"
}
{
  "data.name.first_id": "first_id_value"
}
{
  "data.name.second_id": "second_id_value"
}
{
  "data.name.third_id": "third_id_value"
}
```

But I want the **objects of data to be under the same braces** as 'firstKey' and 'id'.

[LINK to JqPlay](https://jqplay.org/#)

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your structure is so rigid, you can cheat and use the built-in `from_entries`, which takes a list of `{key, value}` pairs and constructs an object:

```
.main[] |
{firstKey, id} +
  (.data | map({key: "data.name.\(.name)", value}) |
   from_entries)
```